# Can anyone tell me what is the error in my code (update query )

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I am creating an update page for the user profile info but it seems that it does not work means that it do not update the user table just the password is updated anything else it never changed can anyone help me ?????

## account_setting.php

```
<?php 
require_once('for members/scripts/connect.php');

ob_start();
session_start();


   $login = ($_SESSION['login']);
   $userid = ($_SESSION['user_id']);
   $login_user = ($_SESSION['username']);
   $email = $_SESSION['email_address'];
   $fname = ($_SESSION['first_name']);
   $lname = ($_SESSION['last_name']);





//functionssss



function specializationQuery(){

$specData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM specialization");

  while($recordJob = mysql_fetch_array($specData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recordJob['specialization_id'] .  '">' . $recordJob['specialization_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}



///end of functionsss 




if($login)
{



$message = "";
$errorMSG = ""; 


    if(isset($_POST['edit_pass'])){
     $oldpassword = $_POST['oldpass'];
     $newpassword = $_POST['pass1'];
     $repeatpassword = $_POST['pass2'];


   ///passwordquerry
   $passwordquery = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = '$userid' ")or die(mysql_error());
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($passwordquery))
   {
       $dbpassword = $row['password'];

       //check for the old password  is equal  dbpassword
       if($oldpassword == $dbpassword)
       {

           if($newpassword == $repeatpassword)
           {
               if(strlen($newpassword) <=8)
               {
                   $message = "your password is less than 8 charachters";
               }
               else
               {
               $password_update_query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET password = '$newpassword' WHERE user_id = '$userid'")or die(mysql_error());
                    $message = "Your password has been updated";
               }
           }
           else
           {
               $message = "your password do not match!!";
           }
       }
       else
       {
           $message = "your password is incorrect!!";
       }
   }

}


    // get the previouse first name and last name from the database and make it the default 

    $get_info = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, last_name, user_name, email_address FROM user WHERE user_id = '$userid'") or die(mysql_error());
    $get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_info);
    $fname = $get_row['first_name'];
    $lname = $get_row['last_name'];
    $username = $get_row['user_name'];
    $email = $get_row['email_address'];



    //submit what the user types into the database
    if(isset($_POST['edit'])){
     $fname = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['fname']);
     $lname = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['lname']);
     $spec = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['specialization']);
     $governorate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['governorate']);
     @$district = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['district']);
     @$village = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['village']);
     $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
     $aboutme = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aboutme']);



      //$about_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (interest) VALUES ('$aboutme')")or die(mysql_error());
    if(strlen($fname) <= 3)
    {
        $errorMSG = "your first name is must be at least 3 charachters ";
    }
    else

     if(strlen($lname) <=4)
      {
          $errorMSG = "your last name is must be at least 4 charachters ";
      }
      else
     $edit_query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET first_name= '$fname', last_name= '$lname', user_name = '$username', email_address = '$email', specialization= '$spec', governorate = '$governorate', district = '$district', village = '$village', interest = '$aboutme' WHERE user_id = '$userid'") or die(mysql_error());
    $errorMSG = "Update successfuly";
    var_dump($fname);
  }
}

else
{
    die("YOU MUST LOGIN FIRST ");
}



 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Edit Profile</title>
<link href="style/stylesheet.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
                $("select#district").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#village").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#governorate").change(function(){
                $("select#district").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#district").html("<option>wait...</option>");
                var id = $("select#governorate option:selected").attr('value');
                $.post("select_district.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                    $("select#district").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("select#district").html(data);
                });
            });
            $("select#district").change(function(){ 
            id = $(this).val(); 
            $("select#village").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#village").html("<option>wait...</option>");
            $.post("select_village.php", {id:id}, function(data){


            $("select#village").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("select#village").html(data);
         });
        });
            $("form#registerform").submit(function(){
                var cat = $("select#governorate option:selected").attr('value');
                var type = $("select#district option:selected").attr('value');
                var village = $("select#village option:selected").attr('value');

            });
    });


</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<!--<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>-->

<br />
<br />
<br />

    <div class="registerTitle">
      <h2>Edit you account setting below </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="eidtProfile">
   <?php echo "welcome <b>$login_user</b> you can now edit your profile"; ?>
   <hr />

      <div id="editProfileImage">
        <p>Upload profile photo</p>

        <!-- check if the user has upload a profile pic or not-->
         <?php
         $check_pic = mysql_query("SELECT profile_pic FROM user WHERE user_name= '$login_user'")or die(mysql_error());
         $get_pic_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_pic);
         $profile_pic_db = $get_pic_row['profile_pic'];
         if($profile_pic_db == "") 
         {
             $profile_pic = "images/default_img.jpg";
         }
         else
         {
             $profile_pic = "userdata/profile_pics/".$profile_pic_db;
         }
         ?>
         <!--upload profile img script-->
         <?php
          if(isset($_FILES['profilepic'])){
   if(($_FILES["profilepic"] ["type"] == "image/jpeg")|| ($_FILES["profilepic"] ["type"] == "image/png") && ($_FILES["profilepic"] ["size"] < 1048576))//1 MB
   {
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
    mkdir("userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name");

     if(file_exists("userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES["profilepic"] ["name"]))
     {
       echo $_FILES["profilepic"] ["name"]."Already exists";    
     }
     else
     {
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profilepic"] ["tmp_name"], "userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES["profilepic"] ["name"]);
         //echo "Uploaded and stored  in: userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES["profilepic"] ["name"];
      $profile_pic_name = $_FILES["profilepic"] ["name"];
      $profile_pic_query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET profile_pic = '$rand_dir_name/$profile_pic_name' WHERE user_name = '$login_user'") or die(mysql_error());
      header("Location: account-setting.php");

     }
   }
   else
   {
       echo " INVALIDE File! your image must not be large than 1MB and .jpg or .jpeg or .png";
   }

 }
 ?>
        <form action="" = "" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <img src="<?php echo $profile_pic; ?>" width="80" />
        <input type="file" name="profilepic" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload Img">
        </form>

      </div>

<hr />
<?php include "select.class.php"; ?>
<form action="account-setting.php" method="post">

<p>Update your Password</p><br />
<p style="color:#FF0000"><?php echo $message; ?></p><br />
Old Password: <input type="password" name="oldpass" id="oldpassword" placeholder="Password" />
New Password: <input type="password" name="pass1" id="newpassword" placeholder="Password" />
Reapet Password: <input type="password" name="pass2" id="repeatpassword" placeholder="Validate Password" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="edit_pass" value="edit password" />
<hr />

<p>Update Your Profile Info</p><br />
<p style="color:#FF0000"><?php echo $errorMSG; ?></p><br />
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Firstname" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>" />

Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Lastname" value="<?php echo $lname; ?>" />
<br />
User Name: <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $login_user; ?>" />

Email_address: <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email address" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
<br />
<br />
Specialization: <select name="specialization"  class="select">
      <option value="0">-- Select Your Specialization --</option>

        <?php specializationQuery(); ?>
      </select>
<hr />
<p>Update Location Info</p>
 Governorate
        <select id="governorate" name = 'governorate'>

                <?php echo $opt->ShowGovernorate(); ?>


                </select>

District
      <select id="district" name="district">
                    <option value="0">choose...</option>
                </select>

Village
       <select id="village" name="village">
                    <option value="0">choose...</option>
                </select>


      <br />
About Me: <textarea name="aboutme" rows="5" cols="30"> </textarea><br />
<input type="submit" name="edit" id="edit" value="edit Profile" />








</form>




    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>

<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: You asked the same question a while ago.

Comment: Your update query only updates password, what else should it update?

Comment: @ Fabio  i divided my update section to 2 section the update of password will  independent of the update of the other information like the username/ password/ first name/ last name/date of birth / email/ and location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first check your all post data values is here then try

```
if(strlen($fname) <= 3 || strlen($lname) <=4)
    {
        $errorMSG = "dhow msg ";
    }
 else {
     $edit_query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET first_name= '$fname', last_name= '$lname', user_name = '$username', email_address = '$email', specialization= '$spec', governorate = '$governorate', district = '$district', village = '$village', interest = '$aboutme' WHERE user_id = '$userid'") or die(mysql_error());
    if ($edit_query) {
       $errorMSG = "Update successfuly";
    }
  }
```

Comment: i did as you prpopsed and now i get the error  undefined  variable : edit_query in ..

Comment: is updated sucessfully?  for this define $edit_query=''; above if()

Comment: the updated sucessfully display when ever the user submit and update for any field  in the update form without the password

Comment: now it work i can update nay field but with a little error i can not update without updating the last name field i think it have something with the if statement

Comment: okkk i fix the error thank you

Comment: i still have a question the $village do not get any value how to fix that??

Comment: remove @ from $village also try to remove disabled from jquery on this